# Objective C Empty Array in Different Class

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Question with trying to simply clear a mutablearray in another class in objective C 
the code all runs fine, just the data doesnt get wiped....

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contactsArray;
```

Thats the declaration of the mutablearray...

then from the class that i am trying to delete it.

listViewController.h

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    SecondViewController *secondViewControl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
```

then in the main file i use the code

```
[secondViewControl.contactsArray removeAllObjects];
```

but then when i check the array it has not been emptied...

EDIT:

```
@implementation ListViewController
@synthesize table;
/*- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}*/

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    secondViewControl = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
```

Comment: When do you setup the reference to secondViewControl?

Comment: Could you post the class implementation of the `ListViewController` class?

Comment: That code looks good to me.

Comment: i have added the code to the main question. Hope this is the right bit. The removeallobjects is called on a click on a table, which i know is called because of a nslog insert

Comment: Did you try to create a new array instead removing all the objects ?
You can use

   `if(secondViewControl.contactsArray){
 [secondViewControl releas];
 [[secondViewControl alloc] inti];
   }`

Insted of `[secondViewControl.contactsArray removeAllObjects];`

Comment: At the point where you call `[secondViewControl.contactsArray removeAllObjects];` add a line to log the value of `secondViewControl`.  At the point in `SecondViewController` where you allocate the array add a line to log the value of `this`.  Make sure they're the same object address.

Comment: Where do you call that `removeAllObjects`? Is the `secondViewControl` non-nil?

Comment: Where do you put the objects in the array?  Perhaps after being removed they are being put back in.